# Дополнительные поля при выборе пункта

Tags: html, javascript

Предположим, есть кнопка `RADIO{form}`

1. Radio: 1
2. Radio: 2

При выборе 1-го пункта добавляются какие-либо поля, при выборе другого другие поля.
С JS не дружу, кто что подскажет?

Comment: учить js, или плати что бы за тебя сделали

Comment: Мне кажется есть готовые скрипты или хотя-бы хоть какое-нибудь примерное решение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p><input type='radio' name='radio' value='1' onclick="hideFields(true)" checked> 1)</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='radio' value='2' onclick="hideFields(false)"> 2)</p>

<div id='hidden_fields'>
        <p>Name: <input ></p>
        <p>Sex: <input ></p> 
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('hidden_fields').style.display = 'none';
function hideFields(hide){
        document.getElementById('hidden_fields').style.display = hide ? 'none' : 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: В редакторе ответа есть кнопка `101010`. Ей одиноко. Вспоминайте про нее время от времени.